# Simple setting retriever from cookies

Tags: javascript

I have a cookie on my site with the following value:

> eyJGIjp0cnVlLCJBIjp0cnVlLCJUIjpmYWxzZSwiUyI6ZmFsc2UsIkciOmZhbHNlLCJYIjpmYWxzZX0%3D

I use this function to retrieve the value from the site so I can use it in the applications my site uses to greenlight certain elements or to block them.

```
function getCookieLawSettings() {
    return document.cookie.split(';')
            .map(c => c.trim().split('='))
            .filter(c => c.shift() == 'cookie_law')
            .map(c => JSON.parse(atob(decodeURIComponent(c.pop())))).pop()
}
```

What kind of improvements could I make on this code? Stylistic and functional.
Are there things I missed/gotcha's I should account for?

sample with dummy data:

```js
document.not_cookie = "_ga=GA1.2.431922604.1523436815; _gid=GA1.2.1579280874.1523436815; cookie_law=eyJGIjp0cnVlLCJBIjp0cnVlLCJUIjpmYWxzZSwiUyI6ZmFsc2UsIkciOmZhbHNlLCJYIjpmYWxzZX0%3D";
function getCookieLawSettings() {
    return document.not_cookie.split(';')
            .map(c => c.trim().split('='))
            .filter(c => c.shift() == 'cookie_law')
            .map(c => JSON.parse(atob(decodeURIComponent(c.pop())))).pop()
}
console.log(getCookieLawSettings());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since (I assume) there should only be a single cookie fragment called `cookie_law` you should use `find` instead of `filter`. `filter` will go through the whole array even if the result is the first element.

As it stands I think that it is bad for a `filter` method to modify the underlying data.

Also the number of parenthesis in the line

```
.map(c => JSON.parse(atob(decodeURIComponent(c.pop())))).pop()
```

is pretty scary. I would pull at least some of that out into another method.

#### update

In my code I usually split out my logic with a method to get any cookie, that way I can reuse it for other cookies. The logic also ends up being simpler.

```
function getCookieLawSettings() {
    return decodeCookie(getCookie('cookie_law'));
}

function getCookie(na,e) {
    var cookie = document.cookie.split(';')
            .map(c => c.trim().split('='))
            .filter(c => c[0] === name);
    return cookie ? cookie[1] : undefined;
}

function decodeCookie(data) {
    return JSON.parse(atob(decodeURIComponent(data)));
}

function encodeCookie(data) {
    return btoa(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify)));
}
```

Comment: The parenthesis is wat led me to post here too. Looked too lispy for my tastes. Just run it through a second map? The find suggestion is a good one. Didn't think of that. And yea, it's just for that specific cookie. I base64 encoded it because urlencoded json was three times as long. Decoding it is how i ended up with the parenthesises.

Comment: @Tschallacka You can just define a `decodeCookie()` function (analogously `encodeCookie()`), so that you run `.map(decodeCookie)`. I'd also replace `.shift()` and `.pop()` calls by immutable operations, e.g. just array indexing `[0]`.

Comment: You could use an extra `map` to replace `c.pop()` but if you use `find` you would have a single element not an array so you would no longer be able to use `map`.